# Data Cleaning - Issues with applying clean to all elements of the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, machine-learning, data-cleaning

Hi I'm attempting my first ML project and am probably way out of my depth. I've been trying to clean the data ready to start NLP, and need to get rid of the punctuation and split the sentences down into single words. I can't seem to get the script to run on all rows in the column, it's only looking at the first line which is the name of the column. In this case 'description'.

I've put the code below that I've run to load the file and pics to show the output at each stage. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def load_user_info():
userdata = pd.read_csv('userinfo.csv')
return userdata
```

### Output from head command

[image: Pic to show output from head command]

### Creation of dataframe

[image: Pic to show creation of dataframe and what data is in there]

### Cleaning the data to remove punctuation etc

```
import re
import string

def clean_text_round1(df):
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub('[%s] ' % re.escape(string.punctuation), ' ', df)
    text = re.sub('\w*\d\w*',  ' ', df)
    replace_no_space = re.compile('\.)|(\;)|(\:)|(\!)|(\')|(\?)|(\,)|(\")|(\|)|(\()|(\))|(\[)|(\])|(\%)|(\$)|(\<)|(\>)|(\{)|(\})')
    replace_with_space = re.compile('<br\s/><bre\s/?)|(-)|(/)|(:).')
    return df
round1 = lambda x: clean_text_round1
```

### Applying the data clean

```
data_clean = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(round1))
data_clean
```

the above command returns:

`description    <function clean_text_round1 at 0x000001726BA53598>`

When I call df I'm expecting to see clean data but as I've said above it only seems to be applying the clean to the first row and not the rest of the data in the description column. I'm getting the same when I try to split the sentences within the dataframe down into single words, it applies the code to line one and ignores the rest of the rows in the column.

Comment: Why are you doing `round1 = lambda x: clean_text_round1` that makes no sense.

Comment: I've been cobbling this together from different things that I've watched and read. I figured that by using the lambda function says for every ‘x’, do the method that a follows to all data, but I obviously don't know enough about it to use it in the right context.

Comment: No, a lambda expression creates a function, that function merely returns your `clean_text_round1` function. You want to just do something like `df.apply(clean_text_round1, axis=1)`, but your function seems broken to me. It refers to an undefined `text` variable